# !is.na in extraction operator working with [[]] and not []

Tags: r

I tried going through the differences between the double square brackets [[]] extraction operator and the single square bracket extraction operator [] but couldn't understand what's causing the following behavior in my code, hence the question.

I have a data frame stored in a variable `outcomedata`, and am aiming to remove the rows containing NA in the variable at column number stored in `outcomeval`. So here's what's working:

`outcomedata <- outcomedata[!is.na(outcomedata[[outcomeval]]),]`

But when I tried using 
`outcomedata <- outcomedata[!is.na(outcomedata[, outcomeval]),]` , it wouldn't clean up those rows. Can somebody please tell me the difference between the two, what exactly is causing this behavior?

Comment: The answer depends on the specific structure of `outcomedata`, so it would help if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616).

Comment: They should both work if `outcomedata` is a dataframe and `outcomeval` is a single value, as you suggest.  Can you post a reproducible example?